# for an online Library how to do the romved function?

Tags: python, list, oop

```
class Book:
    def __init__(self, isbn_no, title, book_format, subject, rentalPrice, copies):
        self.isbn_no = isbn_no
        self.title = title
        self.book_format = book_format
        self.subject = subject
        self.rentalPrice = rentalPrice
        self.copies = copies


from modelBook import Book


class BookFunction:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list_of_books = []


    def add(self):
        _isbn_no = input("Enter the ISBN Number:")
        title  = input("Enter the title od the book:")
        book_format = input("Enter the book format:")
        subject = input("Enter the subject:")
        try:
            rentalPricePerDay = float(input("Enter the rental_price_per_day:"))
        except ValueError:
            print("invalid price program end")
            quit()
        try:
            numberOfCopies = int(input("Enter the number of copies:"))
        except ValueError:
            print("invalid copies program end")
            quit()
        book_ = Book(isbn_no=_isbn_no,title=title,book_format=book_format,subject=subject,rental_price_per_day=rentalPricePerDay,number_of_copies=numberOfCopies )
        self.list_of_books.append(book_)
        print(f'Book added With ISBN No:{_isbn_no}')

    def remove(self):
        _isbn_no = input("Enter the ISBN Number:")
        matched_books = list((an_item for an_item in self.list_of_books if an_item.number_of_copie>0))
        for an_item in matched_books:
            self.list_of_books.remove(x)
            print("Book removed")
```

user need romve the book as he want ?

Comment: If `romve` means `remove`, please [edit] your post and fix the spelling. Please also clarify your question; you have some `remove()` code there, but what issues are you having with it?

Comment: my project is online library   user can come and see the  available book and add the book and remove the book  add book  function is work but remove function is not work so i need to fix it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What does this line actually do:

```py
from modelBook import Book
```

You just defined the `Book` class above it. Is it a part of a (I'm guessing here) Django project?

Regarding `remove` method:

- an ISBN is unique, so you should get only **one** matching element (or none)
- you are trying to remove `x`, which is not defined in the scope of `remove` method (or any other scope in fact)
- the `Book` class instance has no attribute `number_of_copies` it has `copies` (your signatures **do NOT** match), because of that the `add` method doesn't work neither imho

Here's a slightly better version of `remove` method, but keep in mind that without fixing the above the full code won't work anyway.

```py
    def remove(self):
        _isbn_no = input("Enter the ISBN Number:")
        try:
            matched_book = [book for book in self.list_of_books if book.copies>0 and book.isbn==int(_isbn_no)][0]
            self.list_of_books.remove(matched_book)
        except:
            print(f"Couldn't remove book with ISBN: {_isbn_no}")
        else:
            print("Book removed")
```

Side notes:

- use sneak case, not camel case for variable names e.g. `number_of_copies` instead of `numberOfCopies`
- naming a class `BookFunction` makes no sense, it's a class...not a function, maybe `Library` would make more sense from your description
- in general name variables meaningfully and be precise if possible, `book` is better name for iterating over a list of `Book` instances, than `an_item`